# Check cursor closed in java

Tags: java, plsql

How to check if PLSQL cursor is closed from java

i am using the following code

```
stmt.registerOutParameter(25,OracleTypes.CURSOR);
```

if i use the following code

```
if(stmt.getObject(25)!=null)
```

i am getting cursor closed error

please help.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741276/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-a-database-cursor-is-open-or-not-in-java

Comment: Looks like you found a good way. :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to check it with the instance of the statement object:

```
if(!stmt.isClosed()&&stmt.getObject(25)!=null) ...
```